# Create cognito pool id from aws cli or nodeJS got error, what's wrong with the params?

Tags: node.js, google-authentication, amazon-cognito

I created nodeJS scripts to setup my **AWS Cognito Pool ID** using class "CreateIdentityPool":

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
var params = {
    "IdentityPoolName": "samplePool",
    "AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities": true,
    "CognitoIdentityProviders": [
      {
        "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxx-qea4ebra0gipd0krefi37v8f48svrp8e.apps.googleusercontent.com", /* google client ID */
        "ProviderName": "accounts.google.com"
      }
    ],
    "DeveloperProviderName": "mypool"
};
cognitoidentity.createIdentityPool(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

but it got an errors below :

> { [ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value
>   'xxxxxxxxxxx-qea4ebra0gipd0krefi37v8f48svrp8e.apps.googleusercontent.com'
>   at 'cognitoIdentityProviders.1.member.clientId' failed to satisfy
>   constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern:
>   [\w_]+]   message: '1 validation error detected: Value
>   \'xxxxxxxxxxx-qea4ebra0gipd0krefi37v8f48svrp8e.apps.googleusercontent.com\'
>   at \'cognitoIdentityProviders.1.member.clientId\' failed to satisfy
>   constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern:
>   [\w_]+',   code: 'ValidationException',   time: Tue Jan 31 2017
>   21:11:48 GMT+1100 (AEDT),   requestId:
>   'ad2b3366-e79d-11e6-b2e7-578f32ddcea5',   statusCode: 400,
>   retryable: false,   retryDelay: 45.71310137398541 }

Second way, I tried create identity pool id first without **CognitoIdentityProviders** and then run update using class "UpdateIdentityPool" to add CognitoIdentityProviders (unlock the authentication providers). But, it was same issue above.

Third way, I tried create identity pool id with argumen **--cognito-identity-providers** from **aws cli** and still got same issue :

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
>   UpdateIdentityPool operation: 1 validation error detected: Value
>   'xxxxxxxxxxx-qea4ebra0gipd0krefi37v8f48svrp8e' at
>   'cognitoIdentityProviders.1.member.clientId' failed to satisfy
>   constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w_]+

Fourth way, I tried create identity pool id without --cognito-identity-providers from aws cli and then update it from aws cli (add --cognito-identity-providers). it was still same issue.

Very frustated with this issue, I have to set it from nodeJS. So, please don't give suggestion to unlock auth providers from AWS Console. There is very poor references for this issue. Really appreciate if you can link me to the solved references.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `CognitoIdentityProviders` but that is for AWS Cognito User pool. You need to set the `SupportedLoginProviders` for it to work. Like this:

```
var params = {
    "IdentityPoolName": "samplePool",
    "AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities": true,
    "SupportedLoginProviders": {
        "accounts.google.com": "xxxxxxxxxxx-qea4ebra0gipd0krefi37v8f48svrp8e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     }
};
```

Comment: Wow, I dont suspect this solution. Before I thought it is like an alias name, so I filled the value object to be :

SupportedLoginProviders: {
   "accounts.google.com" : "google"
}

It works now

Thank you doorstuck

Comment: I have stuck param again for twitter providers. It needs 2 params for ConsumerKey & ConsumerSecret input. While, SupportedLoginProviders will only accept object with one key string and one value string :

keyname1=value1,keyname2=value2,..., etc

{provider1:accessid1, provider2:accessid2, ..., etc}

How to fill the accessid value with twitter provider which has 2 keys ConsumerKey & ConsumerSecret?

Comment: @MahdiRidho try to put a comma ; in between the key and secret: `key;secret`. And use the provider `api.twitter.com`.

Comment: yes, you are right. it needs ";"

it is the sample :

"api.twitter.com": "ConsumerKey;ConsumerSecret"

Thanks for assist me again :-)